# Finding the commentary of Chazon Ish on Yevamot

Tags: jewish-books, commentaries, chazon-ish

I'm following a [reference](https://www.ccarnet.org/ccar-responsa/arr-211-215/) to *"Chazon Ish,Yev., par. 83, #6"*, which I think is his commentary on Yevamot. Can anyone help me find this source online? Many thanks.

Comment: It's in Chazon Ish on seder Nashim. I don't think you'll find it online you might need someone with access to send you the relevant text. Might be on otzar hachochma but not free.

Comment: This is the only one I found, but I do not think it's the right one. https://hebrewbooks.org/14331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Shmuel (I had no idea the Chazon Ish was on Hebrewbooks), here are some possibilities.

If par. 83 means simman 83, [here is a link](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14331&st=&pgnum=268), although that's hilchos gitin and not relevant to the reference at hand.

His [commentary on Yevamos](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14331&st=&pgnum=425) starts at simman 134, so I'm not sure what's par. 83 in this case.

If it means daf 83, [I don't see comments there](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14331&st=&pgnum=441).

There's also Hilchos Yibum starting [at Simman 115](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14331&st=&pgnum=389).

I'm thinking they meant [Simman 117 par. 6](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14331&st=&pgnum=395), which says what they reference about someone acting like a Jew needing conversion or not. Maybe the Simman number changed over the years?

Comment: Great find. I accidently bumped into it searching on Google :). I agree with you on the last part, that it must be siman 117, par. 6.

Comment: I think that must be it. Thanks so much!